# How to use FactoryGirl with a PostGIS database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, factory-bot, postgis

I am migrating from using MongoDB to a PostGIS database. Using MongoDB I am able to specify a longitude/latitude array with FactoryGirl to mock some data:

```
factory :obj_1, class :my_obj do
  geo [-88.09483, 32.12665]
  ...
end
```

When I do this for a PostGIS model, however, I end up with NULLs in the geo column. Has do I add my mock spatial data to my PostGIS database using FactoryGirl?

Answer (score 3):

To properly initialize mock data using FactoryGirl use the RGeo syntax:

```
factory :obj_1, class :my_obj do
  geo "POINT(-88.09483 32.12665)"
  ...
end
```